# Verificar se uma string é uma data válida

Tags: c#, data

Como verifico se a data é válida ou não em C#?

No VB6 eu fazia assim:

```
If Not IsDate(strAux) Then
```

No caso do C#, como faço?

Meu código em C#:

```
//Data Movimento
string strTxt = fileHeader.Substring(17, 8).ToString("YYYYMMDD");

if (!Equals(strTxt))  // verificar se é data válida  
{
    // logFile "ERRO", "Data de Movimento invalida no Header no arquivo."    
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Eu não entendi o que você quis fazer no seu código, mas, pela descrição do problema, imagino que você esteja procurando pelo método [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact).

Note que o segundo argumento do método é o formato que será usado para validar a string.

```
DateTime data;
bool dataValida = DateTime.TryParseExact(strTxt, "YYYYMMDD", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                         DateTimeStyles.None, out data);

if(!dataValida)
    ...
```

Comment: Muito obrigada!!! isso mesmo.

Comment: @Thathi Você pode marcar a resposta como correta usando o V no lado esquerdo dela.